# jqGrid Delete the position of the window next to the delete line for jqGrid 5.2.0

Tags: jqgrid

jqGrid Delete the position of the window next to the delete line for jqGrid 5.2.0

How to do this for version jqGrid 5.2.0

Here for the version jqGrid 4.13.6 working

http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/OK/formEditOnDoubleClick-jqueryui-fa.htm jqGrid 4.13.6

Comment: "jqGrid" not exist in versions higher as 4.7. Trirand changed the name of the product to "Guriddo jqGrid JS" and the license agreement (see [here](http://www.trirand.com/blog/?p=1438)). Guriddo jqGrid JS is **commercial product** (see the price [here](http://guriddo.net/?page_id=103334)). The current version of Guriddo jqGrid JS is 5.2.0. You can post the questions about Guriddo in [the forum](http://guriddo.net/?forum=guriddo-js).

Comment: Because of making jqGrid commercial I made the fork of jqGrid 4.7 and started to develop it under the name "free jqGrid" (see [here](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid)). It's current version is 4.14.0 (4.13.6 is the previous version of free jqGrid). "Free jqGrid" can be used completely free of charge. Thus there are no "jqGrid 5.2.0" and "jqGrid 4.13.6". You mean "Guriddo jqGrid JS 5.2.0" and "free jqGrid 4.13.6", which are **different** product. Both from there are *alternative* developments (forks) of "jqGrid 4.7".

Comment: Thanks for clarifying Oleg

Comment: You are welcome, Наташа (Natasha)!

Comment: Started the transition from paid 5.2 to your jqGrid 4.14.1-pre - free

And such a mess of malasha is simply horror, it was necessary to make tables at once on your free version

Do you have any examples? as here
http://trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/jqgrid.html#

Comment: I recommend you to look though [the article](https://free-jqgrid.github.io/getting-started/index.html). [The wiki](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/wiki) and READMEs to every previously published version provides additional information about the new features, which exists only in free jqGrid. For example, the README to the last version contains the reference to the demo https://jsfiddle.net/OlegKi/yvbt6w54/, which uses 3-state checkbox in filter toolbar of "Closed" filed, jQuery UI of "Client" field and select2 in "Shipped via" field.

Comment: See [here](https://free-jqgrid.github.io/examples/index.html) some other demos, like `multiPageSelection: true` option and some other new options.

Comment: Thanks Oleg, I will study